# Hibernate HQL left join with null values

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, null, hql

I have those 2 tables

table A with columns: id, description, title

table B with columns: id, user, authent, rel_id

table B rel_id is FK on table A.id (One to One)

```
==> Table A Entity
==> @JoinColumn(name = "REL_ID", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private ObjectTableA objA;
```

now, i want to have with hql the same result as Sql :

```
select *
from tableA a
left outer join tableB b on a.id = b.REL_ID and b.user='ADMIN';
```

which include all table A row ONCE and table B references (including null)

eg.

```
id  -  description  -  title  -   id   - user    -  authent  -  rel_id
1   -  des1         -  tit1   -   6    - admin   -  4        -  5
2   -  des2         -  tit2   -   null - null    -  null     - null
```

The problem with hibernate HQL and the second row above (id=2) is that I cannot reach table A row data by doing EntityB.rel_id because rel_id object(whose type is EntityA) is null thus pointing to nothing which means I cannot show required data on my view!
How can I overcome this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either I don't get the problem right or you have to explain it in another way.

One fact which seems confusing is the mapping you are showing. It says

> Table A Entity

but there is a field of type `ObjectTableA`. Is it possible that this is the source code of `ObjectTableB`. Otherwise for me it looks like a self reference (Entity ObjectTableA contains a field of type ObjectTableA) and would make no sense in this case.

If my assumption is correct and hence your mapping says `nullable=false`, there should never be an Entity B without the proper Entity A. Other way around it is possible that there are a lot of Entities of type A without a related Entity of type B. This is exactly what your second row is about:

> 2   -  des2         -  tit2   -   null - null    -  null     - null

If you want to get all the ObjectTableA Entities your HQL query would be something like:

Query #1: `SELECT a FROM ObjectTableA a;`

If you want to get all the ObjectTableB Entities it would rather be like:

Query #2: `SELECT b FROM ObjectTableB b WHERE b.user =:username;`

If you also want load all the ObjectTableA stuff along to your ObjectTableB Entities write something like:

Query #3: `SELECT b FROM ObjectTableB b JOIN FETCH b.objA AS a WHERE b.user =:username;`

Of course you will only get access to the data of your row in question (Entity A without proper Entity B) with HQL query #1, but that should be comprehensible.